# rijndael algorithm - decryption problems

Tags: c++

I have this code encrypting my file:

```
static const char* KEY = "Test";
```

...

```
    FILE* pFile = fopen("skills.dat", "wb+");

char* result = new char[ (TOTAL_SKILLS + 1) * sizeof(int)];
memset(result, 0, (TOTAL_SKILLS + 1) * sizeof(int));


int counter = 0;
while(counter != TOTAL_SKILLS + 1)
{
    char szSkillName[40] = "";
    strcpy(szSkillName,(buffer + (counter * 0x12C)));

    int skillDelay = *(int*)(buffer + (counter * 0x12C) + 228);


    *(int*)(result + (counter * 4)) = skillDelay;

    counter++;
    printf("Skill %s saved.\r\n",szSkillName);
}
CRC4 crc;
crc.Encrypt(result,KEY, (TOTAL_SKILLS + 1) * sizeof(int));

fwrite(result,1, (TOTAL_SKILLS + 1) * sizeof(int),pFile);
fclose(pFile);
```

the contents of `buffer` may not be important, the problem is that I can't decrypt the encrypted data. I am using the same key, obviously, but the decrypted result is not the same as the original input buffer. What might be happening? This sounds weird...

Decryption code:

```
LPCSTR name = "skills.dat";
    int counter = 0;
std::ifstream myFile(name, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out );

if(myFile.fail())
{
    myFile.close();
    return false;
}

int len = (TOTAL_SKILLS + 1) * sizeof(int);
char* buffer = new char[len];

myFile.read(buffer,len);
myFile.close();

CRC4 crc;
crc.Decrypt(buffer,KEY,len);
```

Comment: You use `counter * 4`, I'm assuming your code is only intended to work on platforms where an integer is 32-bits. Is that correct? Also, you desperately need to add error-checking. How do you know the `myFile.read` succeeds?

Comment: Also, just from what I can tell, RC4 looks totally unsuitable for your application. RC4 is really only suitable with an ephemeral key that is random and will only be used once. Even then, the lack of any data integrity check and fixed value locations would make your data easy to tamper with. For example, I can change the delay of my fifth skill from 10 to 0 just by XORing the 23rd byte with 0x0A.

Comment: which encryption system do you recommend then?

Comment: I hate giving recommendations without a formal statement of your requirements. At minimum, I'd have to know how you plan to generate and store the key and what kinds of threats you're trying to protect against. You could perhaps use RC4 with an HMAC if you generate a new key randomly each time, but I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: no no, not a random key, I plan to use a static key both for encryption and decryption. Not a sofisticated stuff, just good enough to protect normal users to read the file, and as I am going to pack my final executable, it would be even more hard - not impossible - to find out the key used.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be secure, then it doesn't much matter what you do.

Comment: It need to be secure indeed... you dont know any encryption system that uses a fixed key for both encryption and decryption?

Comment: Honestly, it seems to me like you're in way over your head. You really should hire a security expert to flesh out your requirements and threat model and implement a sensible solution. Alternatively, you could try starting over with a question (maybe to crypto.SE) listing your requirements and asking for help finding a suitable solution. It sounds, however, like this is basically a DRM problem with no good solution. (Same entity both authorized to encrypt and decrypt and not authorized to encrypt and decrypt.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the SWAP macro inside the Encrypt function and in the key generation hash.